# how to rearrange the elements of an array according to exact match of a key word

Tags: php, mysql

is it possible to rearrange the elements of an array according to a criteria or keyword?
for example putting the results of a two queries in and array and rearrange them the elements according to the key word putting exact matches first before similar matches.

```
$arr = array();

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE (title LIKE '$key') OR (title LIKE '%$key') OR (title LIKE '%$key%') ORDER BY CASE WHEN title LIKE  '$key' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END DESC") or die (mysql_error());
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
   $li = $data['title'];
   $arr[] = $li;
}

$sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE (title LIKE '$key') OR (title LIKE '%$key') OR (title LIKE '%$key%') ORDER BY CASE WHEN title LIKE  '$key' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END DESC") or die (mysql_error());
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)){
   $li = $data['title'];
   $arr[] = $li;
}

// rearrange elements according to $key
```

Comment: why 3 times `(title LIKE '$key') OR (title LIKE '%$key') OR (title LIKE '%$key%')` ?

Comment: to exact ones, those starting with it and those there is a match within